# When I execute the daphne command, I get an error: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, django-channels

My command is as follows:

```
sudo /home/fanfei/onehomeServer/env/bin/daphne -u /tmp/daphne.sock onehomeServer.asgi:application
```

I got feedback:

```
sudo: unable to execute /home/fanfei/onehomeServer/env/bin/daphne: No such file or directory
```

But this file is in the folder

Comment: Can you show the output of `sudo ls -al /home/fanfei/onehomeServer/env/bin/`

Comment: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 fanfei fanfei     289 Feb 23 15:46 daphne`    @AK47

Comment: @fanfei were you able to solve this?